# Accessing the <img> tag data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access the  tag data so that I can send this image to the server (database) after manipulation using Javascript image processing libraries.

Comment: You wanna process the image in the `img` tag using javascript and send it back to the server?

Comment: what library(ies) are you using? And aren't those libraries support that kind of thing?

Comment: The top hit on Google for "javascript image processing libraries" seems to work with the `<canvas>` tag. Are there really JavaScript libraries which work on `<img>`? I didn't know it was possible to do that.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with HTML5's `<canvas>`:

For canvas support in IE: http://me.eae.net/projects/iecanvas/

- create a canvas:
  `var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
  canvas.setAttribute('width',150);

  canvas.setAttribute('height',150);`
- get the 2D context:
  `var context = canvas.getContext('2d');`
- copy the image into the canvas:
  `context.drawImage(document.getElementById('your_image_id'),0,0);`
- modify as you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial
- get the data URL with:
  `canvas.toDataURL()`

That's it.

Also, look at: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html

Answer (score -1):

The [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) might help you.
It's a free to use java library, You can use it to go through html pages and lookup specific tags to get it's contents.
I don't know how it will work in practice since I haven't had the opportunity to use it yet but my college recommends it

Comment: I think he's looking for a way to send the data itself (e.g. base64 encoded) from the client to the server. HTML Parser is for server-side parsing.

Answer (score -2):

```
<image id="myimage" src="myimage.jpg">
```

javascript:

```
function getImage(){
 var imgsrc = document.getElementById('myimage').src;
 alert(imgsrc + ' is the source!');
 return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking for the `src` attributes, but for the binary data of the image